# Inductive effect of alkyl ammonium groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

> Why $\ce{-NR3+}$ has more *-I* effect than $\ce{-NH3+}?$
>
> And what about order of $\ce{-NHR2+}$ and $\ce{-NH2R+}?$

#### My attempts

I got idea about electronegativity of carbon atom in $\ce{R}$ is more than hydrogen atom, hence positive charge gets more concentrated on nitrogen atom and it exerts more electronic attraction. But this didn't worked out in latter case when *-I* effect of $\ce{-NHR2+}$ is less than $\ce{-NH2R+}.$

Answer (score 1):

The inductive effect is both distance-dependent and χ-dependent. N-H bonds are 1.01 Å, yet the χ of H is only 2.1. N-C bonds are 1.42 Å, yet the χ of C is 2.5. At the extremes, where there are only N-C or N-H bonds, the ordering of *-I* is easy to rationalize.

However, the two, short N-H bonds in -NH<sub>2</sub>R<sup>+</sup> outweigh the higher χ of N-C bonds, giving -NH<sub>2</sub>R<sup>+</sup> a higher *-I* than -NHR<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup>.

Comment: What that X means dipole moment

Comment: @user49564 It's not "X", it's a Greek letter χ ("chi") . Guessing from its numerical values and the fact it's dimensionless, my bet is it's [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity). Mark, it would be nice to add clarification to the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's electronegativity. Thanks :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why are not we considering the +I effect shown by alkyl group and hydrogen atom to determine the order of -I effect in $NR_3+$ and $NH_3+$?